# Design for type casts between objects of similar type

Tags: python, oop

Suppose I have two types of axis aligned rectangles:

a) Defined by left-up and right-bottom points: (x1, y1), (x2, y2)
b) Defined by (x1, y1) and (width, height)

The aim is to create pythonic-way code, that allows for conversion between these types. E.g. if there is a function, that performs calculations only in one of the representations, it calls the necessary conversion on the given rectangle object first.

I can think of three ways of accomplishing that:

1. Create two classes inheriting from a base class. Create two "abstract" methods in the base for conversion to and back between a) and b) with a set of *isinstance* branches inside. Overload the methods in the inheriting classes, making empty methods for useless T -> T conversions.
2. Create a class with one static method, accepting two arguments, unrelated to a) and b)
3. Same as 2., but get rid of the class, just create a function in the global source file scope

Which one do you think is the best way, or may be there is something better?

Comment: Stackoverflow does not accepted questions that does not have clear answers and are primarily based on opinions. It is mostly related to errors and ways to solve problems, your question is probaly more suited on one of the other stack forums.

Comment: @MartinHenriksen: this one has a pretty clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create one class, and give it two constructors. One the default `__init__` method, the other a classmethod accepting the other form to specify a rectangle:

```
class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        # ....

    @classmethod
    def fromSize(cls, x1, y1, width, height):
        return cls(x1, y1, x1 + width, y1 + height)
```

The `Rectangle.fromSize()` class method converts the parameters to the 4-coordinate form and returns a new instance. You store just the one form to specify a rectangle, the extra classmethod is basically just a convenience method.

I picked the 4-coordinate form as the 'canonical' definition here, but if storing the width and height makes more sense for your model, feel free to swap the default and classmethod factories.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating one class and handling the inputs during your init to determine what is present/not present. Then add all the missing parameters based on a calculation. Here is a working example for your situation:

```
class RectangleClass:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2=None, y2=None, width=None, height=None):
        if not x2 or not y2:
            self.x2, self.y2 = self.calculate_points(x1, y1, width, height)
        if not width or not height:
            self.height, self.width = self.calculate_dimensions(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    def calculate_points(self, x1, y1, width,height):
        x2 = x1 + width
        y2 = y1 + height
        return x2, y2

    def calculate_dimensions(self, x1, y1, x2,y2):
        width = abs(x2 - x1)
        height = abs(y2 - y1)
        return height, width  

rectangle = RectangleClass(0, 0, x2=-1, y2=5)
print "Rectangle 1: height: %s, width: %s" % (rectangle.height, rectangle.width)

rectangle = RectangleClass(1, 3, height=2, width=2)
print "Rectangle 2: x2: %s, y2: %s" % (rectangle.x2, rectangle.y2)
```